# index.js not found if located one folder up from index.html when running node local server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, express

I kind of new to node.js
when i run local server with index.js located one directory up from index.htmlthe browser gives me this error:

[image: 404 server response]

[image: index.js directory up]

when i run the server with index.js in the same directory or in a sub folder directory it works fine.

[image: index.js same directory]

but i when i run it as live server it works both ways.

I tried moving it to different folders and changing the name.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: How can I show the directory it is in?

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but in the first picture index.js seems two directories higher than index.html. Maybe try '../../index.js'.

Comment: It might look like it on the screen, but it's one dir up. vs code autocomplete never wrong i guess

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I found it @Vladislav Bykanov It is because `index.html` and app.js or in your case `index.js` should be on the same level of hierarchy i.e
Such as in the given image... Here `js file` and `HTML file` are on same level... App.js is now as `/app.js` only... it is not `../public/app.js`

I am suggesting you not to put `index.html` in public and put it in the normal `../index.html` so that it **doesn't confuse you...**

[image]